# Duplicate links in left hand quick links

Tags: 2016, duplicate, quick-links

Apologies if this is me being dumb but I have searched and been unable to find an answer.

I'm currently playing around just setting up a simple team site. Currently the team site has 2 sub sites and a few lists etc.

I was editing the quick links on the left hand site and moving the links to new positions. As part of this I dragged one of the subsites (change management) underneath the home link I had set up so as to display as indented. After saving I found I now had 2 change management links, one not indented and one now indented below the home link.

Both of these duplicate links have the eye single meaning I am unable to delete either and to make matters worse I tried to move and save the links again and have replicated the issue meaning I now have 5 change management links I am unable to remove. Note hiding one hides them all.

Unfortunately I am unable to provide a screenshot so have tried to be descriptive enough